# Why are my links changing size as I click on them?

Tags: html, hyperlink, navigation, web-inspector

When I click a link on one of my html documents to open another one of my pages, the links to the other pages I have built get bigger except for one which has the smallest font size. I have no CSS attached to the document, I had to temporarily remove it to try and find the bug that's causing it but see nothing. Ive copied the HTML of one page and applied it to the others yet it still acts this way. Im using chrome and the web inspector showed that they've been placed in the body and each page has a different body size.
First page: "681.xxx"px x "170.xxx"px
Second page: "486.xxx"px x "168.xxx"px
Third page:  "612.xxx"px x "167.xxx"px
Last page:  "821.xxx"px x "171.xxx"px

Comment: Please provide the code you tried.

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>INDEX</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
<nav>
  <li><a href="pages/education.html"><h1>
    Education
  <a href="pages/experience.html">
   Experience
  </h1></a></li>
</nav>
</html>

Comment: this is the one thats working properly

Comment: <!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Greg Holtz</title>
   <li><a href="../index.html"><h1>
    Cover Letter
   <a href="education.html">
    Education
   <a href="experience.html">
    Experiences
   <a href="references.html">
    References
   </h1></a></li>
</head>

Comment: I found out the issue was with chrome. When I opened the pages in Microsoft Edge, there were no problems and the links stayed the same size throughout each page. I dont know if this is an issue that Google should know about or if this is normal.